# Jquery onmouseover function not getting triggered on first hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function hover() {
  $('.service-btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.service-img').addClass('hideImage');
    $(this).closest('.service-row').removeClass('hover');
  })
}

function nonHover() {
  $('.service-btn').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.service-img').removeClass('hideImage');
    $(this).closest('.service-row').addClass('hover');
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-row hover" style="background: url('assets/img/hover-bg.png')">
  <div class="container service-row-inner">
    <div class="service-img">
      <img src="assets/img/home-row-1.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="service-details">
      <div class="service-title">
        <h2>Ready to Go</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="service-subtitle">
        <b>100% klaar voor een winters avontuur.</b>
      </div>

      <div class="service-desc">
        <p>Heeft u deze winter een roadtrip of shortski gepland? Ontdek onze all-in ReadyToGo wintercheck, de handigste inpaktips en de beste reisapps van het moment om optimaal te genieten van uw reis.</p>
      </div>

      <a href="" class="service-btn" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="nonHover(this)">
                Meer Info
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem:
The script works but not on the first hover. So if I hover in nothing changes but if I hover out and back in my classes get changed. What could cause this issue?

Comment: would you be able to post your CSS file aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are just adding the `hover` listener when the mouse is over (`mouseover=...`).

**Currently what happens:**
 You start the code and no listener is added to the `a.service-btn` element. When `mouseover` happens you assign the listener to the element, so you need to mouseout and mouseover again to call that new listener you added...

**Solution**:
you don't need that `mouseover` and `mouseleave` on inline HTML, just add the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` listeners directly when JS is loaded. That way you'll have the listener from the start, not adding it just when the first hover occurs.

Code below shows how it work:

```js
$('.service-btn').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.service-img').addClass('hideImage');
  $(this).closest('.service-row').removeClass('hover');
  console.clear()
  console.log("hovering")
})


$('.service-btn').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.service-img').removeClass('hideImage');
  $(this).closest('.service-row').addClass('hover');
  console.clear()
  console.log("not hovering")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-row hover" style="background: url('assets/img/hover-bg.png')">
  <div class="container service-row-inner">  
    <div class="service-desc">
      <p>Heeft u deze winter een roadtrip of shortski gepland? Ontdek onze all-in ReadyToGo wintercheck, de handigste inpaktips en de beste reisapps van het moment om optimaal te genieten van uw reis.</p>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="service-btn">
        Meer Info
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What should I add to have the new background image fade/ease in? Because now it's a bit to instant. Is there a way to add .easIn()?

Comment: sorry, but what does this comment have to do with the original question? I didn't understand...
If it is another question, please open a new question here in StackOverflow